# How do I block a user using their IP with a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, ip

I'm new to this site, I have been coding a script to block certain IPs from a website, the thing is, it all works with the first IP in the column, say for example the database looks like this:

http://gyazo.com/290bc2b9ef77d5b985ddd675ba0c08d1

Then only the first IP, in this case 86.70.***.** would be redirected to the banned page,
If someone could please help me get my php script working:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("bans") or die(mysql_error());  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //Gets the users IP adress

$deny = array( $row[ip]); 
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   header("Location: http://gabbo.org.uk/banned.php"); //What page shall the bans be sent to?
   exit(); 
}?>
```

I would be very grateful!
E. Rosier

Comment: first of all, don't grab all ip's from your db - just query for the existence of the current value of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Comment: secondly, use PDO.

Comment: It seems late in the game to be doing this in your app.  Make your webserver or firewall do it (both of which could get the data from your database if needed).

Comment: use a 403 header response and just display a ban page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Small change in your logic.

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db("bans") or die(mysql_error());
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    # Full Text Attempt
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `IP` FROM `database` WHERE `IP` = '$ip'");
    # Wild Card Attempt
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `IP` FROM `database` WHERE `IP` LIKE '%$ip%'");
    # Use any one query from the above!

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        header("Location: http://gabbo.org.uk/banned.php");
        die();
    }
?>
```

#### Working

When a user with an IP Address of `192.168.1.1` attempts to access your page and your ban list of MySQL has it, it surely returns some rows, which is greater than `1`. That way, the header gives a `301 Permanent Redirection` to the browser to the banned page.

Comment: `select count(IP)` will perform better.

Comment: @TimG Updated. :) Actually, it needs to get the data. So, I thought of skipping that step. BTW, I replaced `*` with `IP` considering performance. :)

Comment: why does it need to get data?  All you want to know is "is this ip on the ban list?"  no data needed.  just a `list($cnt) = mysql_fetch_row( $query );`

Answer (score 0):

The first part is ok, however deny list should be calculated as

```
$deny = array()
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 $deny[] = $row['ip'];
}
```

... than you can continue from if( in_array )

Also the others are right, you should query the database for existance instead of retrieving everything and processing it in php.

And a very strong suggestion: use PDO instead!

Answer (score 0):

You should put the IP lookup in the query:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //Gets the users IP adress

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("bans") or die(mysql_error());  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE ip='$ip'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

if ($row) {
   //What page shall the bans be sent to?
   header("Location: http://gabbo.org.uk/banned.php"); 
   exit(); 
}
```